Is backend access required to view data for direct query Power BI?
I have sensitive data in snowflake.
I want to use the data for creating power BI reports. Now I want the data to be secure to a set of users.
My question is
If i keep the query mode to direct query, will the users not having access to snowflake backend will still be able to see the data in power bi?

If you set the connection to use a defined set of credentials then all users will have access to whatever those credentials give access to. If the connection passes through each user’s credentials then each user will only see the data that use has access to

@NickW Thanks for the answer, just 1 doubt, if I use import mode and connect using current user cred and publish report in service, will the users be able to see dashboard data? Or they also needs to provide access
